# Having trouble accessing /dev/serial0 on a Raspi from within a Module in Azure IoT Edge

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, node-red, azure-iot-edge

I'm trying to set up a Module which will interact with `/dev/serial0` on a Raspberry Pi B+ running Raspian Stretch. I've used `dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt` in `/boot/config.txt`to restore UART0/ttyAMA0 to GPIOs 14 and 15 (which is what my Raspi-based HW needs me to do).

I have attempted to make that device accessible to the Module using the following Container Create Options:

```
{
  "HostConfig": {
    "PortBindings": {
      "1880/tcp": [
        {
          "HostPort": "1880"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Privileged": true,
    "Devices": [
      {
        "PathOnHost": "/dev/serial0",
        "PathInContainer": "/dev/serial0",
        "CgroupPermissions": "rwm"
      },
      {
        "PathOnHost": "/dev/ttyAMA0",
        "PathInContainer": "/dev/ttyAMA0",
        "CgroupPermissions": "rwm"
      },
      {
        "PathOnHost": "/dev/ttyS0",
        "PathInContainer": "/dev/ttyS0",
        "CgroupPermissions": "rwm"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I can see `/dev/serial0` when I ssh in, but I can't see it from within the running Module:

```sh
pi@azure-iot-test:~ $ ls -l /dev/ser*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Sep 24 21:17 /dev/serial0 -> ttyAMA0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5 Sep 24 21:17 /dev/serial1 -> ttyS0
pi@azure-iot-test:~ $ sudo docker exec hub-nodered ls -l /dev/ser*
ls: /dev/serial0: No such file or directory
ls: /dev/serial1: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

**Followup:**

Additional things I have tried the following ideas gleaned from [here](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-docker/issues/15):

- Adding `"User": "node-red"` to the root of the Container Create Options
- Adding `"User": "root"` to the root of the Container Create Options
- Adding `"GroupAdd": "dialout"` to `"HostConfig": {...}` in the Container Create Options

**Followup #2**

While I still can't interact with `/dev/serial0`, I **am able** to interact with `/dev/ttyAMA0` using the following Container Create Options:

```
{
  "HostConfig": {
    "GroupAdd": [
      "dialout"
    ],
    "PortBindings": {
      "1880/tcp": [
        {
          "HostPort": "80"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Devices": [
      {
        "PathOnHost": "/dev/serial0",
        "PathInContainer": "/dev/serial0",
        "CgroupPermissions": "rwm"
      },
      {
        "PathOnHost": "/dev/ttyAMA0",
        "PathInContainer": "/dev/ttyAMA0",
        "CgroupPermissions": "rwm"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The noteworthy items appear to be:

- I didn't need `"Privileged": true` in `"HostConfig"`
- I don't seem to need a "User" added
- I needed `"GroupAdd": ["dialout"]` in `"HostConfig"`

So, while it's satisfying that I can interact with a serial device as I wanted to, it seems odd that I can't interact with `/dev/serial0`, which seems like it's "the recommended way" from the reading I've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to help and insight from [Raymond Mouthaan](https://github.com/RaymondMouthaan) over on the very helpful [Node-RED Slack channel](https://nodered.org/slack/), I found my way to this Container Create Options providing me access to `/dev/serial0`:

```
{
  "User": "node-red:dialout",
  "HostConfig": {
    "PortBindings": {
      "1880/tcp": [
        {
          "HostPort": "80"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Devices": [
      {
        "PathOnHost": "/dev/serial0",
        "PathInContainer": "/dev/serial0",
        "CgroupPermissions": "rwm"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is different than the partial solution I found in "Followup #2" above in that I now do get access to `/dev/serial0` as desired.

**UPDATE:** I originally posted this answer using `"User": "root:dialout"` rather than the `"User": "node-red:dialout"` you currently see above.

The first working solution was with `"User": "root:root"`, but it seemed good to me to constrain to just the devices that are called out in `Devices`, which `root:dialout` seemed to do.

But I wondered whether I should be concerned security-wise with running as `root` at all.

Then I tried using `node-red:dialout` and it seems to be working perfectly, so I've updated the Container Create Options above to be what I think is the best answer.