# Building Docker container for Azure IoT Edge Module with GrovePI+

Tags: azure-iot-edge, grovepi+

I have been experimenting with GrovePI+ running python programs and am looking to extend my experimentation to include integrating with Azure IoT Hub by create Azure IoT Edge modules. I know that I need to update module settings to run with escalated rights so that the program can access I/O and have seen the documentation on how to accomplish that, but I am struggling a bit with getting the container built. The approach that I had in mind was to base the image on the arm32v7/python:3.7-stretch image and from there include the following run command:

```
RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get -y install apt-utils curl &&\ 
    curl -kL dexterindustries.com/update_grovepi | bash
```

The problem is that the script is failing because it looks for files in `/home/pi/`. Before I go deeper down the rabbit hole, I figured I should check and see if I am working on a problem that someone else already solved. Has anyone built Docker images to run GrovePi programs? If so, what worked for you?

Comment: did you get this to work? Especially with the Pi restart that the Grove update shell script requires after it'sinstall?

Comment: It's been a while, but I have a working example at my Github - https://github.com/kyleburnsdev/grovepi-azureiotedge-sample

Answer (score 1):

I've no experience with GrovePi, but remember that modules (Docker containers) are completely self-contained and don't have access to the system. So if that script works when ssh'ed into a device, then I can see why it *would not* work in a module; the module is a little system-in-a-box that has no awareness of or access to locations like `/home/pi/`.

Basically, I'd expect you need to configure the Pi itself with whatever is needed for Grove Pi stuff, then you package your Python into a module. The tricky bit might be getting access to hardware like I2C from within the module, but that's not too terrible. [This kind of thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58100451/having-trouble-accessing-dev-serial0-on-a-raspi-from-within-a-module-in-azure-i/58106205#58106205) is what you'll need (but different devices).